# building fancy report documents? As in what you would see from InDesign etc

Tags: book-design

This one has been puzzling me..
Logically I know it must be possible, if not fiddly to produce fancy looking documents similar to say https://stock.adobe.com/au/140151445?tduid=8da6a0c0dc1dddd1bfb2cf2899b8bb88

But I can't see any trace of them on the interwebs?

What is involved in producing something like this? I'm guessing lots of tikz?

Comment: I don't think that's the main objective of TeX/LaTeX. Fancy short documents are indeed possible, but painful to obtain --- where LaTeX excel is in highly structured, content-oriented documents, especially if with a strong mathematical content. Scribe+inkscape could be a better match for that kind of things.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Yes, it is possible. Yes. it is a lot of work. Maybe you should look into ConTeXt or [Speedata Publisher](https://www.speedata.de/en/), both are suited for elaborate layouts

Comment: There are some older "show nice examples of LaTeX" questions here on the site, for your current question an answer like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60259/ may be interesting.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn  the examples are great - at least this inspires me to do some reverse engineering..

Comment: @DG' ConTeXt combined with exporting from InDesign as XML or HTML has some promise

Comment: @Fran this also looks good :)